# Installing Windows 8 iso Image on USB pen drive for installation purpose on linux

Tags: linux, windows-8, installation

My college offers me a windows 8 system for free so I thought "Yay let's get the games out of the cellar" and downloaded the iso image, but now I have a problem: How do I install the installer image on an USB pen drive on a linux machine? I'm using crunchbang statler, which is a subdistribution of ubuntu.

Some System specs:
Linux 3.2.0-0.bpo.1-686-pae (ubuntu/crunchbang)
i686
enough space to load every random click'n'color-woosh GUI, which aims its purpose, but I'd prefer the terminal-way :D

Comment: This question is not appropriate for this site.  Please see the faq.  http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: "software tools commonly used by programmers"  actually Windows 8 could be also used for extending my Windows development knowledge ;)

Comment: Please read the faq more carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [WinUSB](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/tool-to-create-windows-usb-install.html). You can install it via a ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:colingille/freshlight
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install winusb
```

It comes with an UI and worked fine for me. For using it via terminal use

```
sudo winusb --format <iso path> <device>
```

which formats the whole drive (!) and installs the ISO and the MBR. If you don't want to format the whole drive but just a single partition use

```
sudo winusb --install <iso path> <partition>
```

The partition has to be formated as NTFS. This also writes the MBR.